# I'm confused that this sentence "Jo meets a woman who tells you that she teaches English"

Tags: meaning

I'm confused that this sentence

> Jo meets a woman who tells you that she teaches English

in this sentence, what is the "you" ? Jo ? me ? she?

Comment: Some more context to the question may help, if there is any.

Comment: If I say this sentence to you, *you* is nashile, and *she* is ambiguous— it could be Jo or it could be the woman who Jo met. Where did you find this sentence? Can you provide the entire context?

Answer (score 2):

Your example sentence would usually be understood as (hypothetical scenario)

> 1) You and Jo go to a party
>   2) Jo met a woman
>   3) This woman then told you she is an English teacher
>   *(whether she also told Jo is unknown)*
>
> Jo meets a woman who *(* ***then*** *)* tells you she teaches English.

"**She**" would generally not be understood to refer to Jo, that Jo is an English teacher.

If you think of it as a director talking to an actor and describing the background to a scene it may become clearer.